# Using QGIS Information tool on WMS Image Service

Tags: qgis, wms, imagery, server

I'm new to QGIS but with decent ArcGIS experience.

I'm trying to use the information tool in QGIS to interrogate the date an image was taken from a WMS (https://spatial-img.information.qld.gov.au/arcgis/services/Basemaps/LatestStateProgram_AllUsers/ImageServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS).

When using the same WMS in ArcGIS Pro, the info tool returns the date the clicked image was taken along with other metadata, and I'm trying to achieve a similar result in QGIS but haven't had any luck.

Any advice on where I'm going wrong in QGIS?

[image: QGIS]
[image: ArcGIS]

Answer (score 1):

You must switch to the `Identify Features` tool. When you click on the map it will return the Data from the selected WMS.
[image]

**Update:**
After re-reading your question and testing the `Identify Features` tool on the WMS Link you provided, I think the issue might be that your source is a WMS hosted on an ArcGIS Server. When clicking in QGIS on the WMS in the map it returns `No feature found at that position`, looking in the Debugging/Development Tools also no request is submitted.

So I compared your link with an [OSM WMS](https://maps.heigit.org/osm-wms/service?request=getcapabilities). In your capabilities document the `GetFeatureInfo` capability is missing. Your service only provides `GetCapabilities` and `GetMap`
[image]

The OSM Link on the other hand has additionally a `GetFeatureInfo` capability.
[image]

I guess in ESRI products like ArcMap or ArcGISPro, the client knows how to query the data (when the WMS is hosted via ArcGIS Server or AGOL) but QGIS needs the official `GetFeatureInfo` section in the capabilities document.